# Angular select option field not displaying

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm using `Angular 6`.

In the component.html file, I'm using **FormGroup** and the select field is like

```
<select formControlName="mode_of_payment" type="text" id="input-mode-of-payment" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let mode of modeOfPayments" [(ngValue)]="mode.id" [selected]="mode.id === amountGiven?.mode_of_payment">{{ mode.title }}</option>
</select>
```

The **component.ts** file contains

```
amountGiven: AmountGiven;
updateMoneyForm: FormGroup;
modeOfPayments: Array<ModeOfPaymentData>;

ngOnInit() {

  this._initializeForm();

  // Get mode of payments
  this._getModeOfPayments();
}



private _initializeForm() {
  this.updateMoneyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    mode_of_payment: new FormControl(),
  });
}

private _getModeOfPayments() {
  this.modeOfPaymentService.list().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.modeOfPayments = res;
      this._setFormValue();
    }
  );
}

private _setFormValue() {
  this.updateMoneyForm.setValue({
    mode_of_payment: this.amountGiven.mode_of_payment,
  });
}
```

But this is giving select fields like

[image]

When I click on the select field, the options are pop-up but even there the selected field is not selected by default and always the first option is having a tick mark.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the `selected` directive, the reactive form will take care of that for you :

```
<select [formControl]="modeOfPayment">
    <option *ngFor="let mode of modeOfPayments"
    [ngValue]="mode.id">{{ mode.title }}</option>
</select>
```

[Here is a link to a running code.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52994291)

Comment: I also tried with removed `[selected]` but still it shows blank. Check even your example is showing blank: https://image.ibb.co/mNFUQq/Screenshot-2018-10-26-at-12-05-34-AM.png

Comment: Can you share your browse rand OS, seems like the problem comes from there not from the code.

Comment: The picture you shared is correct, the select has no selected value and the value is the default value. What are you expecting ?

Comment: @AnujTBE I didn't see it is working,may I know the fix.Even I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that chosen a new option will not cause any changes, the TS (type script) attributes.

You need to implement the onchange action on the `select` tag as such.

```
<select formControlName="mode_of_payment" type="text" id="input-mode-of-payment" 
 class="form-control" (change)="someFunction($event)">

    <option *ngFor="let mode of modeOfPayments" [(ngValue)]="mode.id" 
    [selected]="mode.id === amountGiven?.mode_of_payment">{{ mode.title }}</option>

</select>
```

After which you will need to implement the function such as it changes the default selected value.

Comment: But to show the default selected value that is set in the form in `_setFormValue()` function. It always shows blank.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are it's from your css. Remove the form-control class on the select field and it's gonna display. You can write your custom css for the select field.